# TCL script to print range of lines and create the variables

Tags: tcl

Hi I am having a code as stated below

```
module abcd( a , b , c ,da , fa, na , ta , ma , ra ,
              ta, la , pa );

input a , b, da ,fa , na , ta , ma; 
output c , ra ,ta , 
          la ,pa ;
wire a , b , da , fa ,na ,
        ta , ma;


// MBIST Structures
mbist_hsm_p::mbist_out_hsm_t         mbist_out_hsm;
mbist_hsm_p::mbist_in_hsm_t          mbist_in_hsm;

// HMS 
kkkks ;

jsskks;

endmodule
```

Need to take the range between "MBIST Structures " and "//" and the take the first line as a input variable and second line as a output variable.

For example , I am trying below stated code

```
proc findrange {data start {stop ;}} {
    # Find the starting pattern
    set x1 [string first $start $data]
    if {$x1 < 0} {
        # Pattern not found
        return
    }
    # Skip the pattern
    incr x1 [string length $start]
    # Find the ending pattern after the starting position
    set x2 [string first $stop $data $x1]
    if {$x2 < 0} {
        # Return the remainder of the data when no ending pattern is found
        return [string range $data $x1 end]
    } else {
        # Return the text between the starting and ending patterns
        return [string range $data $x1 [expr {$x2 - 1}]]
    }
}


set chan [open "mode.v"]
set code [read $chan]
close $chan

set var4 [ findrange $code "MBIST Structures" \/\/]
```

echo $var4 is printing these variables

```
mbist_hsm_p::mbist_out_hsm_t         mbist_out_hsm;
mbist_hsm_p::mbist_in_hsm_t          mbist_in_hsm;
```

I want to have two lists

```
$input should be "mbist_hsm_p::mbist_out_hsm_t         mbist_out_hsm;"
$output should be "mbist_hsm_p::mbist_in_hsm_t          mbist_in_hsm;"
```

How to create these variables from the var4 variable

When I am trying out to print out the $var4 variable , it is printing 4 independent variables

```
foreach p $var4 {
echo $p
}



mbist_hsm_p::mbist_out_hsm_t
mbist_out_hsm;
mbist_hsm_p::mbist_in_hsm_t
mbist_in_hsm;
```

```
Rather it should be " mbist_hsm_p::mbist_out_hsm_t mbist_out_hsm;"
and other one should be "mbist_hsm_p::mbist_in_hsm_t mbist_in_hsm;"
```

Two lists I am looking for 
$input and $output

Comment: Your two attempts at solving this problem look exactly the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

With a short input file like this, it is much easier to read the whole file into a variable. And for the described task I think `string first` is a better choice than `string match`.

So this is how I would do it:

```
proc findrange {data start {stop ;}} {
    # Find the starting pattern
    set x1 [string first $start $data]
    if {$x1 < 0} {
        # Pattern not found
        return
    }
    # Skip the pattern
    incr x1 [string length $start]
    # Find the ending pattern after the starting position
    set x2 [string first $stop $data $x1]
    if {$x2 < 0} {
        # Return the remainder of the data when no ending pattern is found
        return [string range $data $x1 end]
    } else {
        # Return the text between the starting and ending patterns
        return [string range $data $x1 [expr {$x2 - 1}]]
    }
}

set chan [open "mod1.v"]
set code [read $chan]
close $chan

set out [open "output.file.txt" "w"]
puts $out [findrange $code input]
puts $out [findrange $code output]
close $out
```

There is some change in the white space between your input and the desired
output you specified. But you didn't indicate the rules for that transformation and they are not obvious. So, I am ignoring that for the moment.

Comment: Thanks a lot , I have tried it , I am trying it for one more code but there is some problem over there

Comment: You completely changed the question! Now my answer doesn't make sense anymore. If you have a followup question, don't replace your existing question, but just create a new one.